# Upload image via ModelForm in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

When I try to submit my form it says "This field is required." 
for an image even though I provide the image and other details to it.

**forms.py file**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Status

class CreatePost(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Status
        fields = ["username","text","privacy","image"]
```

**models.py file**

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="updated status")
    username = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/image",null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    gid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dp = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        #unique_together = (('username', 'dp'),)
        #managed = False
        db_table = 'status'
```

**view.py**

```
def create_post(request):
    form=CreatePost(request.POST or None)
    if request.method=="POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.time=time.time()
            instance.save()
            return redirect('post',)

    return render(request,"uposts/createpost.html",{'form':form})
```

**createpost.html**

```
{% extends "friendsbook/structure.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {%csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

What it said after clicking on save button

[image]

I am only taking 4 fields in form because all other fields can be null. For time field I took care of that in views.py by giving the time there.

Comment: which version of django are you in?

Comment: currently i am in 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify the template like this adding multipart/form-data:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and in views.py, you can access the uploaded file using `request.FILES`.

Comment: could you please show me how can i use request.FILES

Comment: You can use like inside request.POST like this `myfile = request.FILES['myfile']`

Comment: Please refer this link for more: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: Still got the same error after using the request.FILES

Comment: could you paste the output of request.POST and form.errors here?